# Semicolon separate numeric filter for kendo grid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I've got some Kendo-Grids in my ASP.NET MVC application. All of them contain an ID column. Currently the ID column has a standard numeric filter for IsEqual, GreaterThan etc.

For this the user has two numeric inputs which both can have one numeric value.

Now it's requested by the customer to be able to input e.g. "1;3;5;9" in the first input and select IsEqual as a result all records with ID 1 OR 3 OR 5 OR 9 should be displayed.

Is there a way to change the Numeric input fields into an input which accepts multiple numbers and semicolons?
And also to change the filter event to be able to build up this custom filter functionality?

This is the implementation of the Id column of the Kendo-Grid

```
info.Bound(c => c.Id).Width(71).HtmlAttributes(new { @class="input-readonly"})
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Operators(o => o.ForNumber(n => n.Clear().IsEqualTo("Is equal to").IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to").IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Is greater than or equal to").IsGreaterThan("Is greater than").IsLessThanOrEqualTo("Is less than or equal to").IsLessThan("Is less than"))));
```

Comment: I'm afraid that the only way to achieve this is to implement both filtering UI and logic by yourself. It's possible to use columnMenuInit or filterMenuInit event to customize the UI. Btw, what are you going to do with "1;3;5;9" and IsLessThan operator?

Comment: The IsLessThan operator was a bit of a bad example in this case. Part of the requirement is also to only allow this semicolon separated filter for the IsEqualTo operator. For all other operators only one number should be allowed as input.